# Meteor - Templates - CSS Styling issues

Tags: css, templates, meteor

I currently have an issue where elements with templates that get iterated with an [[#each]].

The issue being that CSS styles are not affecting them. I am using Stylus to write the CSS. The issue doesn´t limit itself to my own custom CSS styles, but also affects BootStrap styles. The only thing working is inline CSS, but clearly this is not the best approach.

THe code for the application can be found here:https://github.com/smeloa/fcc-voting-app

I have included an example within the code where:

```
<template name="Poll">
    <div class="poll-card" style="border: solid">
        <h3>{{question}}</h3>
        <p>
            {{#each options}}
                {{option}} - {{votes}}
            {{/each}}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Only renders the border style, even though there is a css style saying:

```
/* My Poll Styles */
.poll-card
    margin-top 20px
    color red
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first lines in your original styles.styl started with a TAB character. Stylus messes up the generated css file. You can view the problem when inspecting the css file in the browser.

You probably entered {} around the final css class to prevent Stylus compiler errors for the same reason.

Remove the tabs and replace them with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you have bad formated stylus code: https://github.com/smeloa/fcc-voting-app/blob/master/client/styles/styles.styl#L245 This could be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I have fixed this and the problem remains. When I run the program none of the css styles for the iterated templates show up (looking at this on dev tools).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creting individual stylesheets for each template. Likely will take every single part of the website and break it the same way.

So for example for the NewPoll.html which creates the form to add a new poll I created a NewPoll.styl. This did the trick.